Why does Lambda work differently in VSCode and Jupyter Notebook? (python3)
Why doesn't python Lambda work in VSCode? How is VSCode different from Jupyter Notebook?
from Effective Computation in Physics book there is this Lambda example:

(lambda x, y=10: 2*x + y)(42)


Jupyter Notebook's result is:

94


Meanwhile VSCode has no output, is there some method that VSCode prefers for lambdas and why?

Loosely speaking Jupyter notebook simply decides to show the value of statements / expressions. VSCode just runs your code which produces no output. This is unrelated to lambdas.

That's an expression that resolves to a value. Since that resulting value isn't stored anywhere, python would normally just delete it. An interactive session like jupyter or the python shell would take the extra step of displaying that value before delete - or maybe even assigning it to a temporary variable like _.

By default, Jupyter displays what the last expression evaluates to in each and every cell. You can turn that off or make it evaluate and display the result for each line. See see how last_expr is the default for InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity here. And especially see mbh86's comment below that answer. A REPL is different than a code editor.

No, they run the same functions with Python. It's not really exclusive to VSCode or Jupyter at all.
It's essentially the difference between running a compiler or an interpreter:
In the case of VSCode, or compilers, if you want it to print something, you would have to output it with the print function. Sure, it does evaluate to 94, but it won't do anything with it.
print((lambda x, y=10: 2*x + y)(42)) 

This would suffice.
For Jupyter, it's an interpreter. Equivalent to just running python on your command line and launching the native interpreter on your computer, it would output whatever your expression you give it evaluates to.
As you said, it prints out 94.
======
Addendum:
Technically, VSCode is an integrated development environment (IDE), and you're likely using a compiler within it.
